# How can I bypass lazy loading when testing DQL from the symfony console?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

I think I am hitting a lazy loading feature of doctrine when testing doctrine associations from the symfony console e.g:

```
app/console doctrine:query:dql "SELECT e FROM MyBundle:MyEntity e WHERE e.id=32808"
```

I have a Many-to-one association on that entity and the result shows the related entity with its ID but all other fields are null.

Is there a way to bypass lazy loading when testing from the symfony console?

Comment: I think the problem is your tests.  As long as your relation attribute is not public and as long as you use getEntity() to access the realted entity then all should be well.  Consider posting a few lines from your test.

Comment: @Cerad I am not writing a test in the sense of a unit test, I am just trying to test whether I have set up an association correctly using a symfony console command.

Comment: Which command?  If it a custom command then again, post a few lines of code from it.  The lazy loading should be invisible.  I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The command in the question. Its a standard command from the doctrine bundle. I didnt write it.

Comment: You will need to explicitly join the related entity and then include it in the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch="EAGER"
```

in doctrine annotation in the entity class

[check it out](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone)

worked for me